# Focus text field inside the cell when cell is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want a textarea inside a cell to be focused when I click in the white area of the cell.
At the same time it is also possible to filter that the function is only applied to cells with the class: "use-keyboard-input".

Thanks!

```js
        function textareaFocus(){
            $(this).find('textarea').each(function(){
                $(this).focus();
            });
            console.log('test');
        }
```

```css
table{
  width: 100% !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
}

textarea{ 
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  color: var(--fontDark);
  background-color: red;
}

.routeTable td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.routeTable th{
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.routeTable tr{
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="routeTable"style="border: none;">
  <tbody style="border: none;">
      <tr style=" height: 10em;"><td style="background-color: var(--dark); width: 15%;" colspan="3">Cell-1:</td><td onclick="textareaFocus();" colspan="3"><textarea oninput="saveValues();" style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left;  padding-top: 0.21em;" class="use-keyboard-input"></textarea></td><td style="background-color: var(--dark); width: 15%" colspan="2">Cell-2</td><td  onclick="textareaFocus(); colspan="3"><textarea oninput="saveValues();" style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left; padding-top: 0.21em;" class="use-keyboard-input"></textarea></td><td style="background-color: var(--dark); width: 15%" colspan="3">Cell-3:</td><td  onclick="textareaFocus(); colspan="4"><textarea oninput="saveValues();" style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left;  padding-top: 0.21em;" class="use-keyboard-input"></textarea></td>
      </tr> 
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What IDE do you use? You have incorrect attributes in your markup.

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ali's answer is correct, you can also do it a bit more abstract way.

```js
$('textarea').on('focus', function() {
  console.log('textarea focused');
});

$('textarea').parent('td').on('click', function() {
  console.log('cell clicked');
  
  $(this).find('textarea:first-child').focus();
})
```

```css
table{
  width: 100% !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
}

textarea{ 
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  color: var(--fontDark);
  background-color: red;
}

.routeTable td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.routeTable th{
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.routeTable tr{
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="routeTable"style="border: none;">
  <tbody style="border: none;">
    <tr style=" height: 10em;">
      <td style="background-color: var(--dark); width: 15%;" colspan="3">Cell-1:</td>
      <td colspan="3"><textarea oninput="saveValues();" style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left;  padding-top: 0.21em;" class="use-keyboard-input"></textarea></td>
      <td style="background-color: var(--dark); width: 15%" colspan="2">Cell-2</td>
      <td colspan="3"><textarea oninput="saveValues();" style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left; padding-top: 0.21em;" class="use-keyboard-input"></textarea></td>
      <td style="background-color: var(--dark); width: 15%" colspan="3">Cell-3:</td>
      <td colspan="4"><textarea oninput="saveValues();" style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left;  padding-top: 0.21em;" class="use-keyboard-input"></textarea></td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect thank you to!

Comment: Glad to help ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a reference object to the function to determine which cell is clicked. So I updated the function to `textareaFocus(obj)` and passed td by adding `(this)` as a parameter to the function:

```js
function textareaFocus(obj){
    $(obj).find('textarea').focus();
    console.log('test');
}
```

```css
table{
  width: 100% !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
}

textarea{ 
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  color: var(--fontDark);
  background-color: red;
}

.routeTable td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.routeTable th{
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.routeTable tr{
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.8vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="routeTable" style="border: none;">
    <tbody style="border: none;">
        <tr style="height: 10em;">
            <td colspan="3" style="background-color: var(--dark); width: 15%;">Cell-1:</td>
            <td colspan="3" onclick="textareaFocus(this);">
            <textarea class="use-keyboard-input" oninput="saveValues();" style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left; padding-top: 0.21em;"></textarea></td>
            <td colspan="2" style="background-color: var(--dark); width: 15%">Cell-2</td>
            <td onclick="textareaFocus(this);" colspan="3">
            <textarea class="use-keyboard-input" oninput="saveValues();" style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left; padding-top: 0.21em;"></textarea></td>
            <td colspan="3" style="background-color: var(--dark); width: 15%">Cell-3:</td>
            <td colspan="4" onclick="textareaFocus(this);">
            <textarea class="use-keyboard-input" oninput="saveValues();" style="height: 1.5em; text-align: left; padding-top: 0.21em;"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

You can also do that without calling the function through onclick but by binding a listener to `td` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".use-keyboard-input").click(function(){
        $(this).find("textarea").focus();
    })
})
```

Comment: Super many thanks.
Oh man and actually so simple :D

Comment: Ok. I updated the answer without hard coding the function call. @PatrickGottberg . You can vote up or accept the answer if it worked.